How can I become a better quantum software developer?
How can I become a better quantum software developer? I would like to open source program and such. I'm dedicated and consistent. I'm learning Qiskit right now and I'm planning to learn rust. How should I go about this. I would really appreciate it, thank you.

Hi, and welcome to the Quantum Computing StackExchange! Your post has been closed because it would be a bit hard to provide it with an objective answer. If you edit your post so that this issue disappears, then it can be reopened. Also, note that there is a Software engineering Stack Exchange where you would probably get more accurate answers to your questions. Be sure to check this page before asking it to be sure it won't get closed!
